# Acknowledgment to Acknowledgement

Tags: templates, thesis, acknowledgements

I am writing doctoral dissertation using a template TeX file made by somebody in our school (with 'thesis' document class)

I can add acknowledgement by using

```
\begin{acknowledgment}
```

command, but I don't like the spell.
I understand 'acknowledgment' and 'acknowledgement' both are correct, but I like 'acknowledgement' more.

How can I change this?

Comment: Do you want to change the spelling in the source .tex file or compiled output (e.g., PDF)?

Comment: Ask the person providing the template. it will be the most reliable source. And of coursr ask the prrson to change the name of the class to somethong more specific. There are already 17532 thesis classes.

Comment: Right now, nobody can answer the question as the used template is unknown.

Comment: `thesis` documentclass -- that's pretty unique...

Comment: I solved it. I just changed all 'Acknowledgments' to 'Acknowledgements' in the 'thesis.cls' file.

Comment: I solved it. I just changed all 'Acknowledgments' to 'Acknowledgements' in the 'thesis.cls' file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because was solved by OP (as she/he told in comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new environment `acknowledgement` can be defined that just uses the old one:

```
\newenvironment{acknowledgement}{%
  \begin{acknowledgment}%
}{%
  \end{acknowledgment}%
}
```

Alternatively, the new environment can be defined by assigning the internal macros directly:

```
\let\acknowledgement\acknowledgment
\let\endacknowledgement\endacknowledgment
```

Comment: This will change spelling in the TeX source file but I don't see how it affects the output. Does this change the spelling of "Acknowledg[e]ment" in the compiled document as well? Otherwise, is there a way to alter the environment to do so? Reading between the lines but I think this is what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @TomKelly The question only contains the environment name and asks about a different spelling. It does not say, what the environment is doing, which class is used, how the environment is defined, which language is used, ... Of course, it is possible that the answer does not hit the question precisely, but the OP has the possibility to comment or edit the question to clarify the issue.

Comment: Yes, as it stands you have answered the question. However, I don't think this will affect the output document at all so I don't see the point in doing so. I suspect there has been a misunderstanding here as that's unlikely what the OP really wants to do.